# Angular: Extract keyword from user input - and display it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I would like to to allow the user to order the format of an address in whichever way he/she pleases. 
For this, there will be an input in which the user would type in both keywords and regular text. 
The idea is to detect when a keyword has been entered and extract that keyword from an object and then display it.

This is the object:

```
$scope.address = {
        "addressline1": "Street Name",
        "addressline2": "City and County",
        "addressline3": "12",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "postcode": "XE12 2CV"
    }
```

This is the markup:

```
<input ng-model='value' placeholder="address1, address2, address3, address4" type="text" />
```

The directive should allow any input in the text field - *but* - when a key word is entered as the 'value' then the script should grab that from the address object - and display it.

I am struggling to implement this.

Below is my JS.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
 angular.module('testApp', [])
.controller('testController', hotelController)

function hotelController($scope, $http) {
var vm = this;
$scope.address = {
  "addressline1": "Street Name",
  "addressline2": "City and County",
  "addressline3": "12",
  "country": "United Kingdom",
  "postcode": "XE12 2CV"
}
 var regexMobile = /addressline[0-9]*$/;
 var match = regexMobile.exec($scope.address);
 var result = '';
 var startPoint = 1;

 if (match !== null) {
  for (var i = startPoint; i < match.length; i++) {
    if (match[i] !== undefined) {
      result = result + match[i];
    }
  }
  $scope.value = result;
   }
  }
 })()
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasiev89/txgg0q4b/)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you're using `controller-as-syntax` there's no necessity of `$scope` injection. Also you have a code that will be called only when page loads, you need something like `ngChange` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Antonio, are you trying to display value by key value?? example after enter addressline1 , should return "Street Name" right

Comment: @NagaSaiA  - Yes. But, the trick is to only get that value if a keyword is detected - hence the regex

Comment: @developer033 - yes - no need for $scope. thanks

Comment: Take a look on my answer and let me know if I understood your question correctly..

Comment: Using your answer I can now extract the value of addressline1 - but i need to be able to format the entire address. For example the user would type:
This is [addressline1] and [addressline2] which would then be displayed as
This is streetname and cityname

Comment: @AntonioVasilev ,please my post which gets the value using the keyword without using regex

Comment: Do you want to make it separating by commas? Like: addressline1, addressline2? And what is the expected result of it? This (Street Name, City and Country)?

Comment: @developer033 - Yes - You type: This is, [addressline1] and [addressline2]
and you get as output: This is Street Name and City and County. 
I need to be able to have commas and other words there to format it all.

Comment: i didn't get that what is you want to achieve,  can you put an example that how's output should look like?

Comment: It's done, take a look on my answer.

Comment: @AntonioVasilev checkout the updated codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKjJQV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you're trying to display a *label* based on what user types in the `textbox`.

**Ex:**

User types: "addressline1" so it should display "Street Name".

Then, if I'm correct, the below demo should work:

**EDIT:**

As requested by the author, this edit version shows how to separate items by comma and then display the values from their respective keys:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('testApp', [])
    .controller('testController', hotelController);

  hotelController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function hotelController($scope) {
    $scope.address = {
      "addressline1": "Street Name",
      "addressline2": "City and County",
      "addressline3": "12",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "postcode": "XE12 2CV"
    }

    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.label = "";
      $scope.value.split(", ").forEach(function(value) {
        for (var addressKey in $scope.address) {
          if (addressKey == value) {
            $scope.label += " " + $scope.address[addressKey];
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testController">
  <section class='container'>
    <h5>Type in keyword</h5>
    <p>Custom directive which filters out keywords from an object and outputs them as text</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" placeholder="address1, address2, address3, address4" ng-change="change()">
    <hr>
    <span ng-bind="label"></span>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AntonioVasilev, I noticed that has some bugs in the older version, check the latest to prevent that bugs in your **real code** please.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result , use below

HTML:

```
<main data-ng-app='testApp'>
  <section data-ng-controller='testController' class='container'>
    <h5>Type in keyword</h6>
  <p>Custom directive which filters out keywords from an object   and outputs them as text</p>

  <input ng-model='value' ng-keyup="test()" placeholder="address1, address2, address3, address4" type="text" />
 <div ng-repeat="x in keys| filter:value" ng-show="value">   
    {{x}} : {{address[x]}}
    </div>
</section>
</main>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('testApp', [])
    .controller('testController', hotelController)

  function hotelController($scope, $http) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.address = {
      "addressline1": "Street Name",
      "addressline2": "City and County",
      "addressline3": "12",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "postcode": "XE12 2CV"
    }

    $scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.address);

    $scope.test = function() {
      $scope.result = $scope.address[$scope.value];
    }
  }

})()
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKjJQV

Comment: What it differs from my answer?

Comment: @developer033 i was providing different option to achieve same result,..i need to tweak to dsplay as requested by Antonio in his comment

Comment: Anyway, it seems neither my nor your answer are correct after that last comment.

Comment: Thanks - I accepted the above answer - but you input was usefull too, +1